# Damon taking Elena to a faroff city and bar?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-vampire-diaries

In [The Vampire Diaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vampire_Diaries), S01E11, Why does Damon takes Elena to a far off city and then to a bar?

What was his purpose? In an earlier episode it was said that he does everything with a purpose.

Answer (score 1):

from [Vampire Diaries wikia](http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/Bree%27s_Bar):

> Damon came with Elena here(Bree's Bar in Atlanta, Georgia) in the episode Bloodlines to ask Bree for help. Damon, hoping to release Katherine from the tomb without the crystal, seeks out Bree's help.

Damon needed the help of a witch to know and to open the seal on the tomb of Katherine. Bree was a witch who was on friendly terms with Damon, and hence he went to her to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

He wanted to visit the witch (at the bar) to ask her if she knows how to break the spell or was it something about the necklace. I think he just wanted some alone time with Elena and he wanted to tease Stefan.

Comment: Which necklace?